could not the kubernets configmap
In kubernetes 1.29.x cluster. Fisrt make sure the namespaces contains configmap:
➜  migration kubectl get configmaps -n reddwarf-cache

NAME                           DATA   AGE
cruise-redis-configuration     3      2y334d
cruise-redis-health            6      2y334d
cruise-redis-scripts           2      2y334d
kube-root-ca.crt               1      2y334d
reddwarf-redis-configuration   3      451d
reddwarf-redis-health          6      451d
reddwarf-redis-scripts         2      451d

When I tried to use this command to get the kubernets configmap:
➜  migration kubectl get configmaps -o yaml -n reddwarf-cache- > reddwarf-cache-configmap.yaml

➜  migration cat reddwarf-cache-configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
items: []
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""

the configmap is null, I am sure I can access the config map, why could not get the configmap yaml config from the kubernetes cluster?I also tried:
kubectl get cm -o yaml -n reddwarf-cache- > reddwarf-cache-configmap.yaml


Your last two examples use -n reddwarf-cache- (note the trailing hypen).  Is that a typo?

First, make sure you're specifying the correct namespace (reddwarf-cache)
when retrieving the ConfigMap. 
This command should work correctly:
kubectl get configmaps -o yaml -n reddwarf-cache > reddwarf-cache configmap.yaml

